# How to disable SSL encryption for ODBC connection using DBI package in R?

Tags: r, odbc, unixodbc, r-dbi

I am currently trying to create a connection to SQL Server 2014 via ODBC with the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(odbc)
library(DBI)

odbc::odbcListDrivers()

DBI_Connection <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                  Encrypt = "no",
                  # TrustServerCertificate = "yes",
                  # Trusted_Connection = "yes",
                  # ForceEncryption = "no",
                 Driver = "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server",
                 server = "192.168.0.240",
                 database = "database",
                 uid = "user",
                 pwd = "pass",
                 Port = 1433)

test <- tbl(DBI_Connection, "I07_PARD")

glimpse(test)
```

However I receive this error:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1118: 00000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol]  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute
```

I do not need SSL authentication, but I am not sure how to disable it. I know that ODBC Driver 18 requires encryption on server side by default. How can I disable that?

I am able to configure both client and server.

Comment: Well, it's already there. With encrypt="yes" I get different error:
'Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1118: 00000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol][error:140B40C7:SSL routines:SSL_do_handshake:peer did not return a certificate]  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection. For solutions related to encryption errors, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2226722  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute'

Comment: What version SQL Server are you trying to connect to? Try adding `trustservercertificate: 'yes'` (with `encrypt="yes"`).

Comment: With trustservercertificate: 'yes' (with encrypt="yes") I get the same initial error. I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2014